# Update property of specific item in array using yq 4

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm using yq `4.3.1` to update the `version` field in this yaml:

```
jobs:
  my-job:
    steps:
      - name: Step 1
        id: step1
        uses: actions/step1
      - name: Step 2
        id: step2
        uses: actions/step2
        with:
          version: 1.2.3
```

But I can't figure out how to select the array item based on the `id == 'step2'` property so that I can update the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is it you always figure out the answer the second after you post a question on stackoverflow?

`yq eval '(.jobs.my-job.steps[] | select(has("id")) | select(.id == "step2")).with.version = "1.2.4"' -i my.yaml`

**EDIT**
Wow, how wrong was I... :D Updated with a working version